# Group in list by div class

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Question:**
Can I group found elements by a div class they're in and store them in lists in a list. 
Is that possible?
*So I did some further testing and as said. It seems like that even if you store one div in a variable and when trying to search in that stored div it searches the whole site content.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

result_text = []

# Let's say this is the class of the different divs, I want to group it by
@class='a-fixed-right-grid a-spacing-top-medium'


# These are the texts from all divs around the page that I'm looking for but I can't say which one belongs in witch div
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]")
for element in elements:
    result_text.append(element.text)

print(result_text )
```

**Current Result:**
I'm already getting all the information I'm looking for from different divs around the page but I want it to be "grouped" by the topmost div.

```
['Text11', 'Text12', 'Text2', 'Text31', 'Text32']
```

**Result I want to achieve:**

The 
text is grouped by the `@class='a-fixed-right-grid a-spacing-top-medium'`

```
[['Text11', 'Text12'], ['Text2'], ['Text31', 'Text32']]
```

**HTML: (looks something like this)**
`class="a-text-center a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left"` is the first one that wraps the group from there on we can use any div to group it. At least I think that.

```
</div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a-fixed-right-grid a-spacing-top-medium"><div class="a-fixed-right-grid-inner a-grid-vertical-align a-grid-top">
        <div class="a-fixed-right-grid-col a-col-left" style="padding-right:3.2%;float:left;">

    <div class="a-row">
        <div class="a-fixed-left-grid a-spacing-base"><div class="a-fixed-left-grid-inner" style="padding-left:100px">
        <div class="a-text-center a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-left" style="width:100px;margin-left:-100px;float:left;">

<div class="item-view-left-col-inner">








    <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/product/B07YCW79/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o0_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1">

<img alt="" src="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rcskoL._SY90_.jpg" aria-hidden="true" onload="if (typeof uet == 'function') { uet('cf'); uet('af'); }" class="yo-critical-feature" height="90" width="90" title="Same as the text I'm looking for" data-a-hires="https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41rsxooL._SY180_.jpg">

    </a>


</div>
        </div>
        <div class="a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right" style="padding-left:1.5%;float:left;">


    <div class="a-row">





    <a class="a-link-normal" href="/gp/product/B07YCR79/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s0?ie=UTF8&psc=1">

        Text I'm looking for

    </a>


    </div>
    <div class="a-row">
```

Comment: you'll have to first find that div then for each element in that find the texts. can you supply the link?

Comment: Yes, I can but there is a login required. So sadly that wouldn't help you :/

Comment: do the divs you want to group by have the same class each or at least an identifiable class?

Comment: I think they have the same class `@class='a-fixed-right-grid a-spacing-top-medium'`

Comment: @TenaciousB This sadly won't do the job. `divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-fixed-right-grid a-spacing-top-medium']")
    for i_div in divs:
        for element in divs.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]"):
            result_text .append([element.text])

    print(result_text )`

Comment: I posted an answer using: `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a-fixed-right-grid')` AFAIK you can only put one class tag in `find_elements_by_class_name()`

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the link to test it on but this might work for you:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

result_text = [[a.text for a in div.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]")]
               for div in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a-fixed-right-grid')]

print(result_text)
```

EDIT: added alternative function:

```py
# if that doesn't work try:

def get_results(selenium_driver, div_class, a_xpath):
    div_list = []
    for div in selenium_driver.find_elements_by_class_name(div_class):
        a_list = []
        for a in div.find_elements_by_xpath(a_xpath):
            a_list.append(a.text)
        div_list.append(a_list)
    return div_list

get_results(driver,
            div_class='a-fixed-right-grid'
            a_xpath="//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]")
```

If that doesn't work then maybe the xpath is returning EVERY matching element every time despite being called from the div, or another element has that same class name farther up the document

Comment: The `result_text` seems now to get all the `href` texts from my "Current result" and stores them in lists. Like this `[['Text11', 'Text12', 'Text2', 'Text31', 'Text32'], ['Text11', 'Text12', 'Text2', 'Text31', 'Text32'], ['Text11', 'Text12', 'Text2', 'Text31', 'Text32']]`

Comment: hmm... there are probably other elements in the tree with that class name, try the other class name or finding that div from xpath

Comment: So what I guess it's doing is, Grouping all `href`text values for all divs found into single lists. But I want to Group the `href` values for each div in it's own list.

Comment: In your new edit are a few errors I can't run it. a "," is missing then you reference `a`which is not defined and you for loop is missing a `in`

Comment: I don't get it. It's still fetching the whole site content. Probably `a_xpath="//a[contains(@href, '/gp/product/')]"`simply doesn't only look at the given div instead it looks through the whole side. Seems like this is whats returning kind of a recursive search in combination with the given div. It's still grouping all divs and it's contents by the given div.

Comment: yeah I think its the xpath string, that's why I dont use xpath much anymoe

Comment: `xpath contains` alone is returning exactly what I want but as said sadly not grouped so not relatable from what div it comes. One div could be fruits and one vegetables. And I simply want these both in two separate lists instead of in one. As the items themselves are already all there.

Comment: Do the <a> tags have a common class?

Comment: No they all have the same `class="a-link-normal`

Comment: I've updated the question with the HTML I want to extract

Comment: So I did some further testing and as said. It seems like that even if you store one div in a variable when trying to search in that stored div it searches the whole site content.